# return не работает?

Tags: javascript, функции, return

Есть список объектов и функция, которая проверяет наличие определенного объекта по имени, а также некоторое свойство в объекте..
Вопрос - почему при вызове функции lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName") не возвращается "No such contact"? Ведь по идее это должно произойти на первом же объекте, так как там нет имени Kristian.

```js
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[i][prop];
    }
    if (contacts[i].firstName == name && !contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return "No such property";
    }
  }
    if (contacts[i].firstName != name) {
      return "No such contact";
    }
}

  console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
```

Comment: Потому что цикл for завершает работу функции раньше, задолго до строки `return "No such contact";`

Comment: Вот как я понимаю этот код: начинается цикл for, его первая итерация это contacts[0]. Проверяются условия if, первые два не проходят проверку. Но (contacts[0].firstName != "Kristian")  же является правдой? Так что должен исполниться return "No such contact"; и функция должна завершиться. В чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: «(contacts[0].firstName != "Kristian")» — внутри цикла нет такой проверки, она стоит ПОСЛЕ цикла

Comment: Я только сейчас заметил, что третье условие находится вне цикла. Писал код в три ночи, совсем голова расплавилась. Поставил третье условие в цикл и теперь всё работает как должно. Спасибо Вам.

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно поставить табуляции, то станет ясно, что третий `if` находится за пределами цикла:

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[i][prop];
    }
    if (contacts[i].firstName == name && !contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return "No such property";
    }
  }
  // тут цикл уже кончился!
  if (contacts[i].firstName != name) {
    return "No such contact";
  }
}
```

Вообще не очень понятно, что в данном случае будет в `i` (цикл то кончился и его переменная `i` тут уже не видна), и если в области видимости нет такой переменной, то последний `if` даст ошибку, если до него дойдёт ход.